# Can't get Label to display value from combo box selection

Tags: c#

C# Winforms User control here.

So I have a label object named alcohol. My combo box object is named snryeastTypeComboBox. I want to keep the number for alcohol for math later.
I'm trying to display the number in a label yet it isn't working... any ideas?

```
public void snryeastTypeComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (snryeastTypeComboBox.SelectedText == "CSM")
    {
        var alcoholTolerance = 14;
        alcohol.Text = alcoholTolerance.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: did you debug the code.. can it be that snryeastTypeComboBox.SelectedText == "CSM" is not true in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand your question, I think you need to fire the event when you select a value from  your combo box. If that is the case you should subscribe to `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of `TextChanged`.

`TextChanged` event should be used if the user can change the value by typing in your combo box.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
public void snryeastTypeComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (snryeastTypeComboBox.Text == "CSM")
    {
        var alcoholTolerance = 14;
        alcohol.Text = alcoholTolerance.ToString();
    }
```

Replace .SelectedText with just .Text.

Comment: I would also agree with @Yogi, that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event would be a better event to use here, but the change above is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this your code needs to be written inside the event `SelectedIndexChanged` instead of `TextChanged`.

Instead of `SelectedText` you should use `Text`

The below code will work fine.

```
private void snryeastTypeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (snryeastTypeComboBox.Text == "CSM")
        {
            var alcoholTolerance = 14;
            alcohol.Text = alcoholTolerance.ToString();
        }

    }
```